# Issue when returning to previous screen using Flutter_bloc

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

I have two screens. The first screen is a list of records from the Firebase database. It looks like this:

```dart
class HomeView extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocConsumer<AuthenticationBloc, AuthenticationState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        if (state is AuthenticationFailure) {
          Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const WelcomeView()),
              (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
        }
      },
      buildWhen: ((previous, current) {
        if (current is AuthenticationFailure) {
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      }),
      builder: (context, state) {
        return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
              actions: <Widget>[
                IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(
                      Icons.logout,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      context
                          .read<AuthenticationBloc>()
                          .add(AuthenticationSignedOut());
                    }),
                IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(
                      Icons.update,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      String? displayName = (context.read<AuthenticationBloc>().state
                      as AuthenticationSuccess)
                          .displayName;
                      context.read<DatabaseBloc>().add(DatabaseFetched(displayName));
                    })
              ],
              systemOverlayStyle:
                  const SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.blue),
              title: Text((state as AuthenticationSuccess).displayName!),
            ),
            body: BlocBuilder<DatabaseBloc, DatabaseState>(
              builder: (context, state) {
                String? displayName = (context.read<AuthenticationBloc>().state
                        as AuthenticationSuccess)
                    .displayName;
                if (state is DatabaseSuccess &&
                    displayName !=
                        (context.read<DatabaseBloc>().state as DatabaseSuccess)
                            .displayName) {
                  context.read<DatabaseBloc>().add(DatabaseFetched(displayName));
                }
                if (state is DatabaseInitial) {
                  context.read<DatabaseBloc>().add(DatabaseFetched(displayName));
                  return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                } else if (state is DatabaseSuccess) {
                  if (state.listOfEntryData.isEmpty) {
                    return const Center(
                      child: Text(Constants.textNoData),
                    );
                  } else {
                    return Center(
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: state.listOfEntryData.length,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return Card(
                            child: ListTile(
                              title: Text(
                                  state.listOfEntryData[index].title!),
                              subtitle:
                              Text(state.listOfEntryData[index].date!),
                              onTap: () {
                                context.read<DatabaseBloc>().add(EntrySelected(index));
                                print('selectedIndex is $index');
                                Navigator.of(context).push(
                                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const SelectedEntryView()));
                              },



                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                } else {
                  return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());

                }

              },
            ),
            floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton (
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const NewEntryView()),
                        (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
              },
              backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
              child: const Icon(Icons.add),
            )
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Then I select any item from this list and I am taken to a screen that contains all the information I need. For example, the title of the article, its body and date.

It looks like this:

```dart
class SelectedEntryView extends StatelessWidget {
  const SelectedEntryView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<DatabaseBloc, DatabaseState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        if (state is SelectedEntryLoaded) {
         final int selectedIndex = state.selectedIndex;
         return Scaffold(
            body: SafeArea(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Text(state.listOfEntryData[selectedIndex].title!),
                  Text(state.listOfEntryData[selectedIndex].text!),
                  Text(state.listOfEntryData[selectedIndex].date!)
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );

        } else {
          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

And it's cool! Everything works exactly as I intended. But! When I press the back button, I get a CircularProgressIndicator instead of going back to the previous screen where my list is.

If I click on a special button in the AppBar, then the list of records is loaded. And then I can again select any entry and go to its screen.

But I want it to happen automatically when the back button is tapped. How to fix it?

Because right now it looks like when I return from the screen with the SelectedEntryLoaded state, the previous screen does not take the DatabaseSuccess state. That is, I get on the screen what is described in this part of the code:

```dart
else {
return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
}
```

Comment: When you press the back button, do you modify the state of `DatabaseBloc`?

Comment: Where is the provider for your DatabaseBloc?  Is it possible you're creating a new DatabaseBloc instance and your state is getting reset?

Comment: I have just realized what the problem was. I didn't have a condition
```if (state is SelectedEntryLoaded)```.

Accordingly, when I returned from the recording details screen, each time I received ```return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());```.